# Migration to new Spotify SDK

Tags: sdk, spotify

Our IOS application uses Spotify SDK for audio streaming, but we have been warned that it will stop working soon. Could someone to help us with the following questions:

Can we use new Spotify SDK without installing a Spotify application?(https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/blob/master/README.md)

Has Spotify any private / paid SDKs that we could use to increase the functionality of our application?

Spotify backend uses DRM encoding technology when streaming audio. In order to use a different player (not from SDK) or can we do without it?

Is it possible to play Spotify stream with another player? If so, which one?

Is it possible to formally redirect Spotify stream through our backend?